# Hibernate one to one unidirectional shared primary key issue

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to implement one to one unidirectional mapping with shared primary keys...(ref...https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association)

The db structure which I am using is as follows,

```
Table Name : HUMANBODY
Columns : ID , NAME

Table Name : HEART
Columns : ID , NAME
```

And the entity mappings are,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "humanbody")
public class HumanBody {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "bodygen", sequenceName = "humanbody_swq")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "bodygen")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Heart getHeart() {
        return heart;
    }

    public void setHeart(Heart heart) {
        this.heart = heart;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private Heart heart;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "heart")
public class Heart {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

The problem I am facing is, if I save the humanbody entity, the primary key is not populated properly in heart entity, it's updating primary key as 0 in the db in the HEART table.

Below is the code snippet using to save the humanbody entity.

```
        HumanBody body = new HumanBody();
        body.setName("human1");

        Heart heart = new Heart();
        heart.setName("human1heart");

        body.setHeart(heart);

        session.save(body);
```

Not sure what wrong I am doing?. Could anyone please help out on this?...

Comment: I think you forgot to add generation strategy in ID property( @GeneratedValue). try with adding it.

Comment: Thanks @Mitul Sanghani, it worked after adding generation strategy.

Comment: Hi all, could You provide complete mappings? I'm facing same problem but I'm unable to use strategy and @GeneratedValue properly (throws exceptions).